Trying to use Graph API to automate upload of files to sharepoint
I have been having this issue for the past week and have been unable to fix it. The program spits this error at me:
Response Status code: 400
Response content: b'{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Resource not found for the segment \'Shared Documents\'.","innerError":{"date":"2024-04-23T19:22:18","request-id":"4c101e09-125e-4adc-b062-247acec1c9b9","client-request-id":"4c101e09-125e-4adc-b062-247acec1c9b9"}}}'

I have checked and do have necessary permissions for the API so that cannot be the issue, very high chance it has something to do with the usage of URL:
- url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{destination_folder}/drive/root:/{filename}:/content"
...
- destination_folder = "msteams_xxxxxx-site/documents/folder/sub-folder" <-more or less

Thoughts, my formatting must be incorrect?
Thought I'd add the chunk of code relevant:
def upload_batch(files, destination_folder, access_token):
    for source_file_path, destination_file_path in files:
        try:
            # Upload file to SharePoint using access token
            filename = os.path.basename(destination_file_path)
            url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{destination_folder}/drive/root:/{filename}:/content"

            headers = {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
            }
            with open(source_file_path, 'rb') as f:
                response = requests.put(url, data=f, headers=headers)

            if response.status_code == 201:
                print(f"Uploaded file: {source_file_path} to {url}")
            else:
                print(f"Failed to upload file: {source_file_path}. Status code: {response.status_code}")
                check_upload_error(source_file_path, destination_folder, access_token, response)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error uploading file: {source_file_path}. {e}")

def check_upload_error(file_path, destination_folder, access_token, response):
    print(f"Checking upload error for file: {file_path}")
    print(f"Destination folder: {destination_folder}")
    print(f"Response status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"Response content: {response.content}")

# Usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    source_directory = r"C:\Users\me\Documents\contains files to be uploaded\files to be uploaded"
    destination_folder = "msteams_xxxxxx-the site/Shared Documents/folder/subfolder"

    try:
        upload_files(source_directory, destination_folder)
        print("Upload completed successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during upload process: {e}")

